# how initialize variable in MERGE MATCHED WHEN CASE Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-merge

I am new to PL/SQL merge command. Can any one help me. I want to add new record MERGE MATCHED THEN case or initialization new variable in Match THEN Case of MEGE query of ORACLE.

```
MERGE INTO table itr
WHEN MATCHED THEN
Update Set
/*Here to add new record or initialization new variable*/
WHEN NOT MATCHED
Insert values
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ORA-06550: line 91, column 10: PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   while try to add new record or initialization new varibale

Please any one help me.

Comment: What issue you have?

Comment: ORA-06550: line 91, column 10:
PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword while try to add new record or initialization  new varibale

Comment: You are missing Using command

Comment: can you provide me example?

Comment: see this: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Comment: Show us the **complete** statement ([**Edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34716425/edit) your question, don't post code in comments)

Answer (score 2):

MERGE statement pseudocode

```
MERGE into <target table>
USING
    <souce table/view/result of subquery>
ON
    <match condition>
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    <update clause>
    <delete clause>
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    <insert clause>
```

Comment: I think no want to delete clause. I want to  'add new record or initialization new variable'

Comment: Its optional clause here for your reference, you can omit it.